# How to get the user input in Java?

Tags: java, input

I attempted to create a calculator, but I can not get it to work because I don't know *how to get user input*.

How can I get the user input in Java?

Comment: Uh, what's your question?  You just posted some code and said you don't like pointers.  Not understanding pointers can still come back to bite you in java if you don't understand pass by reference and pass by value.

Comment: you should try to learn java reading a book, Java How to Program, 7/e is a nice one

Answer (score 382, accepted):

You can use any of the following options based on the requirements.

### [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
//...
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.next();
int i = scan.nextInt();
```

---

### [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) classes

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
//...
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

---

#### [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) class

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
//...
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
int i = dis.readInt();
```

The `readLine` method from the `DataInputStream` class has been *deprecated*. To get String value, you should use the previous solution with BufferedReader

---

#### [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class

```
import java.io.Console;
//...
Console console = System.console();
String s = console.readLine();
int i = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine());
```

Apparently, this method does not work well in some IDEs.

Comment: Note that `DataInputStream` is for reading binary data. Using `readInt` on `System.in` does *not* parse an integer from the character data, it will instead reinterpret the unicode values and return nonsense. See [`DataInput#readInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt--) for details (`DataInputStream` implements `DataInput`).

Comment: this is great, would love to see the required imports added for completeness. It would also really help those who need it.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more helpful if it mentioned what the requirements actually were. I've started a bounty to try to fix this.

Comment: For completness sake, you could actually just `System.in.read()` too since `System.in` is an `InputStream` anyways, no need to for any of the wrappers  x'] Although that's definitely frowned upon.

Answer (score 427):

One of the simplest ways is to use a `Scanner` object as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
//once finished
reader.close();
```

Comment: If you close a Scanner object opened to System.in, you will not be able to reopen System.in until the program is finished.

Comment: @ksnortum can i reopen by `Scanner reader1 = new Scanner(System.in);`?

Comment: Try it.  I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah, ksnortum is right, you get a NoSuchElementException. Somewhat useful related question about [why you cannot reopen System.in after closing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555283/why-is-not-possible-to-reopen-a-closed-standard-stream/33555444).

Answer (score 45):

You can use the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class or the Console class

```
Console console = System.console();
String input = console.readLine("Enter input:");
```

Comment: i think System.console will return null if this code runs from eclipse.

Comment: I believe this will return an error running from almost any IDE. confirmed that intelliJ is having the same issue.

Comment: but why is this a null in eclipse?

Answer (score 21):

You can get user input using [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String accStr;  

System.out.println("Enter your Account number: ");
accStr = br.readLine();
```

It will store a `String` value in `accStr` so you have to parse it to an `int` using [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

```
int accInt = Integer.parseInt(accStr);
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is how you can get the keyboard inputs:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name");  
String name = scanner.next(); // Get what the user types.
```

Answer (score 18):

The best two options are `BufferedReader` and `Scanner`.

The most widely used method is `Scanner` and I personally prefer it because of its simplicity and easy implementation, as well as its powerful utility to parse text into primitive data.

**Advantages of Using Scanner**

- Easy to use the `Scanner` class
- Easy input of numbers *(int, short, byte, float, long and double)*
- Exceptions are unchecked which is more convenient. It is up to the programmer to be civilized, and specify or catch the exceptions.
- Is able to read lines, white spaces, and regex-delimited tokens

**Advantages of BufferedInputStream**

- BufferedInputStream is about reading in blocks of data rather than a single byte at a time
- Can read chars, char arrays, and lines
- [Throws checked exceptions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/)
- Fast performance
- Synchronized ([you cannot share `Scanner` between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672989/meaning-of-scanner-isnt-synchronized))

---

*Overall each input method has different purposes.*

- If you are inputting large amount of data `BufferedReader` might be
  better for you
- If you are inputting lots of numbers `Scanner` does automatic parsing
  which is very convenient

**For more basic uses I would recommend the `Scanner` because it is easier to use and easier to write programs with. Here is a quick example of how to create a `Scanner`. I will provide a comprehensive example below of how to use the `Scanner`**

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in); // create scanner
System.out.print("Enter your name");       // prompt user
name = scanner.next();                     // get user input
```

(For more info about `BufferedReader` see [How to use a BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265693/how-to-use-buffered-reader-in-java) and see [Reading lines of Chars](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/inputstream/read-line-of-chars-from-console-with-inputstream/))

---

### **java.util.Scanner**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException; // import the exception catching class
import java.util.Scanner; // import the scanner class

public class RunScanner {

    // main method which will run your program
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // create your new scanner
        // Note: since scanner is opened to "System.in" closing it will close "System.in". 
        // Do not close scanner until you no longer want to use it at all.
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // PROMPT THE USER
        // Note: when using scanner it is recommended to prompt the user with "System.out.print" or "System.out.println"
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");

        // use "try" to catch invalid inputs
        try {

            // get integer with "nextInt()"
            int n = scanner.nextInt();


            System.out.println("Please enter a decimal"); // PROMPT
            // get decimal with "nextFloat()"
            float f = scanner.nextFloat();


            System.out.println("Please enter a word"); // PROMPT
            // get single word with "next()"
            String s = scanner.next();

            // ---- Note: Scanner.nextInt() does not consume a nextLine character /n 
            // ---- In order to read a new line we first need to clear the current nextLine by reading it:
            scanner.nextLine(); 
            // ----
            System.out.println("Please enter a line"); // PROMPT
            // get line with "nextLine()"
            String l = scanner.nextLine();


            // do something with the input
            System.out.println("The number entered was: " + n);
            System.out.println("The decimal entered was: " + f);
            System.out.println("The word entered was: " + s);
            System.out.println("The line entered was: " + l);


        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("\tInvalid input entered. Please enter the specified input");
        }

        scanner.close(); // close the scanner so it doesn't leak
    }
}
```

---

<sup>Note: Other classes such as `Console` and `DataInputStream` are also viable alternatives.</sup>

<sup>`Console` has some powerful features such as ability to read passwords, however, is not available in all IDE's (such as Eclipse). The reason this occurs is because Eclipse runs your application as a background process and not as a top-level process with a system console. [Here is a link](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-console-class) to a useful example on how to implement the `Console` class.</sup>

<sup>`DataInputStream` is primarily used for reading input as a primitive datatype, from an underlying input stream, in a machine-independent way. `DataInputStream` is usually used for reading binary data. It also provides convenience methods for reading certain data types. For example, it has a method to read a UTF String which can contain any number of lines within them.</sup>

<sup>However, it is a more complicated class and harder to implement so not recommended for beginners. [Here is a link](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-datainputstream-class) to a useful example how to implement a `DataInputStream`.</sup>

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and call the winner here. Mostly pretty great answer, although I wish it went more into depth on when I would want to use `DataInputStream`-- the description there sounds identical to the use case for `Scanner`: reading data into primitives. Also, if someone is at the stage where they don't know how to get user input, most likely they also don't understand why some parts of the standard library wouldn't be available in certain IDEs. Certainly that is the case for me-- why is `Console` unavailable?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I have tried to update to include more clarification. See https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-data-input-streams-and-scanner-classes-in-Java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601520/what-is-the-difference-in-these-ways-to-read-in-user-input

Comment: Perfect. Now this is exactly the answer this question needed all along. If only there were some way I could get it to the top.

Comment: Well, anyone who is willing to scroll down will get a good answer and slowly it will go up :)

Comment: Thanks. Detailed informative answer. Adding `try-with-resource` would make it better.

Comment: Where would you recommend such usage? The reason I have not added a try with resources for the `Scanner` is because closing it will dispose the `System.in` which means it is unavailable for later use in the program.

Answer (score 14):

You can make a simple program to ask for user's name and print what ever the reply use inputs.

Or ask user to enter two numbers and you can add, multiply, subtract, or divide those numbers and print the answers for user inputs just like a behavior of a calculator.

So there you need Scanner class. You have to `import java.util.Scanner;` and in the code you need to use

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Input is a variable name.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your name : ");
s = input.next(); // getting a String value

System.out.println("Please enter your age : ");
i = input.nextInt(); // getting an integer

System.out.println("Please enter your salary : ");
d = input.nextDouble(); // getting a double
```

See how this differs: `input.next();`, `i = input.nextInt();`, `d = input.nextDouble();`

According to a String, int and a double varies same way for the rest. Don't forget the import statement at the top of your code.

Also see the blog post ["Scanner class and getting User Inputs"](http://javalearnsimply.weebly.com/5/post/2014/02/scanner-class-and-getting-user-inputs.html).

Answer (score 9):

To read a line or a string, you can use a `BufferedReader` object combined with an `InputStreamReader` one as follows:

```
BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inputLine = bufferReader.readLine();
```

Answer (score 8):

Here, the program asks the user to enter a number. After that, the program prints the digits of the number and the sum of the digits.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println(
            "Please enter a number to show its digits");
        num = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(
            "Here are the digits and the sum of the digits");
        while (num > 0) {
            System.out.println("==>" + num % 10);
            sum += num % 10;
            num = num / 10;   
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is your program from the question using `java.util.Scanner`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = 0;
        System.out.println("The super insano calculator");
        System.out.println("enter the corrosponding number:");
        Scanner reader3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(
            "1. Add | 2. Subtract | 3. Divide | 4. Multiply");

        input = reader3.nextInt();

        int a = 0, b = 0;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        // get user input for a
        a = reader.nextInt();

        Scanner reader1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the scend number");
        // get user input for b
        b = reader1.nextInt();

        switch (input){
            case 1:  System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + add(a, b));
                     break;
            case 2:  System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = " + subtract(a, b));
                     break;
            case 3:  System.out.println(a + " / " + b + " = " + divide(a, b));
                     break;
            case 4:  System.out.println(a + " * " + b + " = " + multiply(a, b));
                     break;
            default: System.out.println("your input is invalid!");
                     break;
        }
    }

    static int      add(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs + rhs; }
    static int subtract(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs - rhs; }
    static int   divide(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs / rhs; }
    static int multiply(int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs * rhs; }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to create so many `Scanner` objects; one would have been sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputval = input.next();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
int integer=input.nextInt();
String string=input.next();
long longInteger=input.nextLong();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just one extra detail.  If you don't want to risk a memory/resource leak, you should close the scanner stream when you are finished:

```
myScanner.close();
```

Note that java 1.7 and later catch this as a compile warning (don't ask how I know that  :-)

Comment: But *not* if Scanner is open to System.in.  You won't be able to reopen Scanner to System.in again in your program.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more developed version of the accepted answer that addresses two common needs:

- Collecting user input repeatedly until an exit value has been entered
- Dealing with invalid input values (non-integers in this example)

**Code**

```
package inputTest;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class InputTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter integers. Type 0 to exit.");

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            try {
                int n = reader.nextInt();
                if (n == 0) {
                    done = true;
                }
                else {
                    // do something with the input
                    System.out.println("\tThe number entered was: " + n);
                }
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("\tInvalid input type (must be an integer)");
                reader.nextLine();  // Clear invalid input from scanner buffer.
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
Please enter integers. Type 0 to exit.
Enter an integer: 12
    The number entered was: 12
Enter an integer: -56
    The number entered was: -56
Enter an integer: 4.2
    Invalid input type (must be an integer)
Enter an integer: but i hate integers
    Invalid input type (must be an integer)
Enter an integer: 3
    The number entered was: 3
Enter an integer: 0
Exiting...
```

Note that without `nextLine()`, the bad input will trigger the same exception repeatedly in an infinite loop.  You might want to use `next()` instead depending on the circumstance, but know that input like `this has spaces` will generate multiple exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class Daytwo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number ");

        int n = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered " + n);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `throws IOException` beside `main()`, then

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name");
String name = input.readLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to get input in java, all you have to do is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GetInputFromUser
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a;
        float b;
        String s;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered string " + s);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered integer " + a);

        System.out.println("Enter a float");
        b = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("You entered float " + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: its the same thing. You can always just initialize an array with datatype varName[] OR datatype[] varName

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Myapplication{
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         int a;
         System.out.println("enter:");
         a = in.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Number is= " + a);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be something like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int i = reader.nextInt();
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.println("I love java");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get user input like this using a BufferedReader:

```
    InputStreamReader inp = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inp);
    // you will need to import these things.
```

This is how you apply them

```
    String name = br.readline();
```

So when the user types in his name into the console, "String name" will store that information.

If it is a number you want to store, the code will look like this:

```
    int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Hop this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user input using `Scanner`. You can use the proper input validation using proper methods for different data types like `next()` for `String` or `nextInt()` for `Integer`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

//reads the input until it reaches the space
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String str = scanner.next();
System.out.println("str = " + str);

//reads until the end of line
String aLine = scanner.nextLine();

//reads the integer
System.out.println("Enter an integer num: ");
int num = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("num = " + num);

//reads the double value
System.out.println("Enter a double: ");
double aDouble = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.println("double = " + aDouble);


//reads the float value, long value, boolean value, byte and short
double aFloat = scanner.nextFloat();
long aLong = scanner.nextLong();
boolean aBoolean = scanner.nextBoolean();
byte aByte = scanner.nextByte();
short aShort = scanner.nextShort();

scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the best program in the world! ");
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a query: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            if (s.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("The program is ending now ....");
                break;
            } else  {
                System.out.println("The program is running...");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple code that uses the `System.in.read()` function. This code just writes out whatever was typed. You can get rid of the while loop if you just want to take input once, and you could store answers in a character array if you so choose.

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Root 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Root();
    }

    public Root()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < System.in.available(); ++y)
                { 
                    System.out.print((char)System.in.read()); 
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the following:

```
public String readLine(String tPromptString) {
    byte[] tBuffer = new byte[256];
    int tPos = 0;
    System.out.print(tPromptString);

    while(true) {
        byte tNextByte = readByte();
        if(tNextByte == 10) {
            return new String(tBuffer, 0, tPos);
        }

        if(tNextByte != 13) {
            tBuffer[tPos] = tNextByte;
            ++tPos;
        }
    }
}
```

and for example, I would do:

```
String name = this.readLine("What is your name?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard entry using Scanner is possible, as others have posted. But in these highly graphic times it is pointless making a calculator without a graphical user interface (GUI).

In modern Java this means using a JavaFX drag-and-drop tool like [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) to lay out a GUI that resembles a calculator's console. 
Note that using Scene Builder is intuitively easy and demands no additional Java skill for its event handlers that what you already may have.

**For user input, you should have a wide TextField at the top of the GUI console.**

This is where the user enters the numbers that they want to perform functions on.
Below the TextField, you would have an array of function buttons doing basic (i.e. add/subtract/multiply/divide and memory/recall/clear) functions.
Once the GUI is lain out, you can then add the 'controller' references that link each button function to its Java implementation, e.g a call to method in your project's controller class.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvgWgpGZVKc) is a bit old but still shows how easy Scene Builder is to use.

Comment: This answer has been downvoted - no reason given. To me it's the only usable way to get user input into a Java application.

Comment: This is very useful, and I don't see why it was down-voted. However, the current answers and the bounty statement imply that they are looking for an answer for future users who want to gain input via a console.

Comment: I just don't see any Java user - barring those stuck with code written in old versions of Java - having any use for Scanner keyboard input. Last time I'm answering a bounty-tied post . . .

Comment: I understand your complaint completely. I personally believe your answer is very useful so I do not understand why it was down-voted. However, I have on many occasions written programs that do not have GUI's and so I do believe that the proper code for a `Scanner` is very good to have available.

Comment: If the OP said it was some low-overhead (embedded?) process with minimal or no screen I/O, fair enough -  Scanner is what they need. But they stated no such thing. The OP essentially asked us to either accept that this phrase, "user input", **primarily** suggests *keyboard* input or else invited us to interpret the phrase for ourselves . . .

Comment: Ah, yes I can see the confusion. Actually the OP showed console based code as context for his question. Only as of a few years back was the answer edited (for some reason) and the code removed. With that code as context the OP clearly was looking for a simple console solution. I don't know why the posted was edited but I assume it was when the question was 'protected'.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to get user input would be to use Scanner. Here's an example of how it's supposed to be used:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {
public static void main(String[]args) {
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int a;
String b;
System.out.println("Type an integer here: ");
a=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Type anything here:");
b=sc.nextLine();
```

The line of code `import java.util.Scanner;` tells the program that the programmer will be using user inputs in their code. Like it says, it imports the scanner utility. `Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);` tells the program to start the user inputs. After you do that, you must make a string or integer without a value, then put those in the line `a=sc.nextInt();` or `a=sc.nextLine();`. This gives the variables the value of the user inputs. Then you can use it in your code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using JOptionPane you can achieve it.

```
Int a =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter number:");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userinput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Name : ");
        String name = input.next();
        System.out.print("Last Name : ");
        String lname = input.next();
        System.out.print("Age : ");
        byte age = input.nextByte();

        System.out.println(" " );
        System.out.println(" " );

        System.out.println("Firt Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + lname);
        System.out.println("      Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class ex1 {    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a, b, c;
        a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        c = a + b;
        System.out.println("c = " + c);
    }
}
// Output  
javac ex1.java
java ex1 10 20 
c = 30
```

Comment: The sanction for accessing elements of `args` without checking the length of that array first: downvote.

Comment: [`java ex1`](https://s3.amazonaws.com/lowres.cartoonstock.com/computers-technology-explosion-explosive-explode-computer-aba0956_low.jpg)