# How to use BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but I can't seem to get it. I'm working on an assignment for a Data Structures course. It involves pulling data from a simple .dat file. We had never used any of the file-accessing options in Java before, so the professor just gave us the working code for that piece.

A class called `FileReadExample` creates a new `BufferedReader` object, opens a file, and then is supposed to kick out a bunch of data about that file.
But I cannot access any of the data at all.

In a separate `testMain` file, I created a new `FileReadExample` object named `fr` and then attempted to print out things like `fr.readLine()` from there, but it tells me there is no such method.

I'm sure I'm missing something staggeringly easy.

The professor's code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileReadExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("got here");
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("sample-file.dat")));
            System.out.println("File open successful!");

            int line = 0;
            for (String x = in.readLine(); x != null; x = in.readLine())
            {
                line++;
                System.out.println(x);
                if (line <= 3)
                {
                    String[] tokens = x.split(" ");
                    System.out.println("Number of tokens in line " + line + ": " + tokens.length);
                    System.out.println("The tokens are:");
                    for (String token : tokens)
                    {
                        System.out.println(token);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    String[] tokens = x.split("\\|");
                    System.out.println("Number of tokens in line " + line + ": " + tokens.length);
                    System.out.println("The tokens are:");
                    for (String token : tokens)
                    {
                        System.out.println(token);
                    }
                    Integer[] values = new Integer[tokens.length];
                    Integer sum = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                    {
                        sum += Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File I/O error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have goolged.  And YouTubed.  And searched here.   By everything I can see, it should be working.  The only thing that I found that could be the problem is that it is all contained in a try/catch.  But I'm not sure why that matters.

Comment: The code you just posted is working fine for me. Do you get an exception or any error message?

Comment: It compiles, but when I run my test main the cursor blinks and the program ends.  Nothing happens, even though the code has a bunch of printlns in it.  I guess my question is how to call data from a BufferedReader object within a FileReadExample object created in a separate test main.

Comment: Just sorted your formatting out.  The easiest way I find with java => stackoverflow is to format it all properly in your favourite editor first then copy paste the code into a new file, select all lines and hit tab/indent to get it recognised as code when you post here.  Then paste in from that.

Answer (score 81):

Try this to read a file:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    File file = new File("sample-file.dat");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You must put your code in try-catch block because you are to read a file and an exception may be thrown at any chance

Comment: If the method throws an IOException you do not need the try-catch block. BTW other answers for this question are also missing the try-catch block, so this is just an example how to read a file.

Comment: where is your method lols see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16265790/2277645

Comment: I updated my code; happy now? And regarding your own example please close the BufferedReader appropriately like I just did. In your example the BR will not get closed if an exception is thrown during br.readLine().

Comment: dear lols i have used it ok don't get angry friend +1 now

Comment: +1 vote up dear ok done a good job

Comment: What if reader is null when reaching the .close() ?

Comment: A simple `if (reader != null)` check before closing should suffice.

Comment: Becarefull, if the buffer is not empty and does not end by a line termination character, your loop while is blocking

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand fr is the object of your FileReadExample class. So it is obvious it will not have any method like fr.readLine() if you dont create one yourself.

secondly, i think a correct constructor of the BufferedReader class will help you do your task.

```
String str;
BufferedReader buffread = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.dat")));
str = buffread.readLine();
.
.
buffread.close();
```

this should help you.

Comment: That makes sense.  So the FileReader creates it's own Buffered Reader object called 'in'.  So I have an object in my testMain called fr, that should have within it a BufferedReader object that should be accessible.  From the test main, how do I call that?

fr.in.readLine() doesn't work.  

The code that you've provided here should go in FileReader or the main?  Thanks, and again, sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: how about you create a method inside FileReadExample class which uses the in.readLine() method and returns a String value. So eg. if you create a method called String readALine() which returns str. you can use it in your testMain class like this-> mystr = fr.readALine();

Comment: Boom.  That got it.  Accessor method, should have thought of that.

Thanks.