# Can't read data from a file in java

Tags: java, file-io

Here is the problem I want to solve https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/100/

and here is my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application
    File file = null;
    try{
    FileReader f = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ranaa\\Desktop\\merna1.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
    String getContent;
    while((getContent=br.readLine())!=null){
        int content = Integer.parseInt(getContent);
        System.out.println(content);
        if(content %2==0)
            System.out.println("1");
        else
            System.out.println("0");
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

no output appears to me nor exception.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: maybe your code is waiting for the String path = scan.nextLine();

Comment: sorry mistyped...i edit the code

Comment: how merna1.txt looks like?

Comment: This post is for a challenge. I just wanted to clarify if anybody else was working on the challenge.

Comment: @Leo it contains numbers like 1245 and the next line 3424 and so on

Comment: @PhotographyBum how many points people that are getting the answers from SO are earning in this challenge? :-)

Comment: Using a debugger, what is `br.readLine()` the first time the `while` loop is reached?

Comment: @PhotographyBum i just need to know my mistake as i am beginner in programming .. thats all

Comment: @MikeK only the first number and then "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "

Comment: @Leo I don't know the points, but it wouldn't be hard if somewhat answered it with a fully done perfect coding ;) Memo I understand I just wanted the community to understand.

Comment: Then you may want to update your question with that information, especially the `NumberFormatException`, since "no output appears to me nor exception" is no longer true.

Comment: @memoamam I posted an answer hope it helps you

Comment: @memoamam your code runs perfectly in my pc

Comment: I ran your code. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Before seeing my code

First, it is good to put whatever is closeable in `try catch block with resources` so there is no need to be worried about closing it at end because closing connection is done implicitly. read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Second, How to use `BuffeRreader` just take a look at this

[How to use Buffered Reader in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265693/how-to-use-buffered-reader-in-java)

Third, How to use `Scanner` just take a look at this

[How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-could-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class)

Code:

```
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\KICK\\Desktop\\number.txt";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           int current = Integer.parseInt(line);

            if( current % 2 == 0)
                System.out.println("1");
            else
                System.out.println("0");
        }
    } catch (Exceptio e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

or you can use `Scanner` class

Code:

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\KICK\\Desktop\\number.txt";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try(Scanner input = new Scanner(file)){
           while(input.hasNext()){
                int current = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

                if( current % 2 == 0)
                    System.out.println("1");
                else
                    System.out.println("0");
                     }
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
       }
```

output:

```
0
0
1
```

number.txt content :

```
701
4123
2936
```