# Reading file line by line- terminating while loop after reaching last line

Tags: java, loops, io

Program to read file and print all the characters that are letters, throws a NullPointerException when it gets to the last line.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader file = new FileReader(new File("source.txt"));

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(file);

        String line = read.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                line = read.readLine(); // this is where the problem is. When it reaches the last line, line = null and the while loop should terminate!
                if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))) {
                    System.out.print(line.charAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to look into the javadoc for the BufferedReader you are using. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Self help is the best help.

Also note this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265693/how-to-use-buffered-reader-in-java

The answer here will be the same.

Comment: Why do you try and read as many lines as the line's length? That doesn't really make sense

Comment: While loops only check the condition(s) at the **start** of each iteration.  They will not terminate mid loop just because the condition will be false at the start of the next iteration.

Comment: @fge This was supposed to be a minimum working example of a bigger problem. I've updated the code so that it iterates through each character and prints it if it's a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loops do not work like how you explained them in your comment:

> // this is where the problem is. When it reaches the last line, line = null and the while loop should terminate!

While loops only check the condition(s) at the **start** of each iteration. They will not terminate mid loop just because the condition will be false at the start of the next iteration.

So this null check you have at the start `while (line != null)` will only and always happen at the **start** of each iteration, even if `line` was set to `null` mid iteration

So as others have shown you can either construct your while loop as:

```
String line = null;

while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))) 
        {
            System.out.print(line.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

and remove all other `read.readLine()` statements from your code. (which is the shortest lines of code).

Or if you want to be more explicit for perhaps more readability, you can keep the initial `read.readLine()` as you have it but move the iterative `read.readLine()` to after all your uses for line are done:

```
String line = read.readLine();

while (line != null) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))) 
        {
            System.out.print(line.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    line = read.readLine();
    //line is never used after this so an NPE is not possible
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just realize you can do like this:

```
   String line = null;

    while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
        for(int i=0; i<line.length(); ++i)
        {
          if(Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i)))
             System.out.println(line.charAt(i));
        }
    }
```

Do not forget to close streams, and it would be better to encapsulate everything in try block.

Comment: Zach This was supposed to be a minimum working example of a bigger problem. But I got that wrong. :( I've updated the code so that it iterates through each character and prints it if it's a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)` does not make sens here. The length of a line has nothing to do with the number of lines in the file.

Change your code to :

```
String line = null;
while ((line = readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line.length());
    // do what ever you need with line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `while((line = read.readLine()) != null)`

This initializes the value as its checked against the while condition at every loop iteration.