# FileInputStream cannot be converted to Reader

Tags: java, netbeans, jflex

I am trying to read my text file "inputFile.txt" but system shows the error below.
Can anyone help me to solve this error? Thank you!

> error: incompatible types: FileInputStream cannot be converted to Reader
>               Yylex yy = new Yylex(fin);

```
    //create file object
    File infile = new
    File("C://name//test_jflex//inputFile.txt");
    int ch;
    StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(infile);
        Yylex yy = new Yylex(fin);
        Yytoken t;
        while ( (t = yy.yylex()) != null )
            System.out.println(t);
        fin.close();
    }
```

Comment: `new Yylex(new BufferedReader(fin));` or just directly `new Yylex(new FileReader(infile))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two java.io.Reader and java.io.FileInputStream are incompatible. This is because FileInputStream works with bytes and Reader is interface for character streams. If you go to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html you will see that FileInputStream does not implement Reader. That why you need to choose either use Reader + his implementation classes or use FileInputStream.

Example with FileInputStream: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-in-java-fileinputstream/

Example with Reader's one implementation java.io.BufferedReader: [How to use Buffered Reader in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265693/how-to-use-buffered-reader-in-java)

P.S. Please close all the streams appropriately. Your fin.close(); should not be closed in try part!

Good Luck!