# Correct syntax for main method

Tags: java

This is a total beginners question. I am new to java and have been browsing StackOverflow and CodeReview. I am finding these two different formats being used:

[example 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25949/is-it-wrong-to-write-an-entire-program-under-one-class-method-in-java):

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

or
[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

This is what I have in my course notes:

> These words are called modifiers. The main() method is also preceded by the word void to indicate that it does not return any value. Also the main() method always has a list of command line arguments that can be passed to the program
>
> main(String[] args)
>
> which we are going to ignore for now.

So, as you can see, we have been told to ignore this for now, but I'd like to know:

Is there an actual difference between these, if so, what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
> ```
>
> This declaration is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];
> ```

Comment: @ThinksALot Yes, `matrix` (and `rowvector` and `colvector`) are arrays.

Answer (score 4):

*Actaully there are no difference between two `main-method` defination and both are correct.*

But by convention java prefers array declaration as `String[] args` rather than `String args[]`.

So it is more conventional -

```
public static void main(String[] args){...}
```

Answer (score 4):

main method accepts arguement in String array
following ways are accepted

```
public static void main(String args[])
public static void main(String []args)
public static void main(String... args)
```

Answer (score 1):

All these are valid declarations of the main function in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // code
}

static public void main(String[] args) {
    // code
}

static public void main(String args[]) {
    // code
}

public static void main(String[] MarkElliotZuckerberg) {
    // code
}

public static void main(String... NewYork) {
    // code
}
```

- The keywords public and static are interchangeable but mandatory.
- The parameter of the main method can take the var-args syntax.
- The name can be anything..!

These are examples of invalid main method declarations -

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    // public is missing
}

public void main(String args[]) {
    // static is missing
}

public static int main(String... Java) {
    // return type not void

    return 0;
}

public void Main(String args[]) {
    // "main" not "Main"
}

public void main(string args[]) {
    // "String" not "string"
}

public void main(String.. SayHi) {
    // Ellipses is 3 dots !
}
```

I'm sorry if the source code is not soo readable... I always had trouble posting source code... :P ... Hope this helps...! If it did, let me know by commenting..!

Source - [Java Tutorials on Theory of Programming](https://theoryofprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/05/26/java-tutorials-introduction/)