# Java: User Defined Path to csv to be read by scanner

Tags: java, csv

I'm doing something for class and I need to know how to take a string the user inputs via the nextLine() method and use it as the path to a csv file.

Example output would be like this:

```
Enter the name of the input file:
/Users/user/file.csv
```

And that would define the csv in java to be read from and delimited by a scanner instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java

Comment: Assuming you weren't going to let the user input the file path, how would you do it?  Now assume you were going to get String input from the user for some other reason and do something with it.  How would you do that?  If you can do both of those individually, combining them should be no problem.