# How do I create multiple console inputs for different variables?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My goal is to have the user be prompted for multiple separate inputs that would store the data in a manner that I could then manipulate.

For example:

```
Question:
What is your username?
What is your name?
Input:
Sparkeyy
Nelson
```

I then want to be able to take these and add them / multiply if they're numbers. This is what I have so far. (Also first question so sorry for poor formatting)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program{

public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your username is " + username);

}
    public static void (name){

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name     = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name);

}
}
```

Comment: You need a method name here `public static void (name){`.  You need some sort of array if you want to store multiple inputs, and you need to use loops!

Comment: "(Also first question so sorry for poor formatting)" I guess I'll be that guy; you could have also done the formatting before posting; it's not like we prevent you from doing it.

Comment: Are [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) and [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, they answered you're question thoroughly:

[**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java)

You basically need a Scanner, like you're doing, and then for numbers:

```
scanner.nextInt();
```

There are also ways of converting properly formatted **Strings** to **Ints/Doubles**.