# Getting coordinates for 2D Array within ONE function

Tags: java, function, coordinates

How can I retrieve X and Y coordinates from a user within one function?(For java game needing coordinates for array)

**"The getX function will ask the user for an X coordinate. It will return the number once entered by the user. getY has the same function, the message is adjusted to ask for the Y coordinate."**

This is what I need to follow by for the function.
The return values need to be used to place a number in a 2D Array.
How do I achieve this in one function?

```
board[x][y] = 1;
```

EDIT: I can only do some much within java (for computing test, so marks won't be awarded for using anything out of what we have been taught - AQA AS Level).
I need to scan inputs from the user in the function and return both coordinates to be used by the 2D array in main.

Please tell me if I am being confusing or I am not making sense and I'll try and explain better.

If there is no way to do it this way, just tell me.
JimiiBee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are great resources here on actually getting user input. [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java). to create the array I would make something like this:

```
public int[] getCoord(int[] coords) {
    coords[0] = getInt("Please enter x coordinate:");
    coords[1] = getInt("Please enter y coordinate:");
    return coords;
}
```

This would be called like this:

```
coords = getCoord(coords);
```

Which would replace the old value of coords with the new values.

A `getInt` method would look like this:

```
private int getInt(String prompt) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(prompt);

    int in = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();
    return in;
}
```

Of course this could be consolidated into a single method that avoids repeated opening and closing of a scanner, but if you are using `getInt()` elsewhere in the code, this may still be a preferred solution.

If you're forced into using separate methods, we'd rather not have to open and close the scanner repeatedly, instead we'll pass the scanner in from the getCoord class.

```
public int[] getCoord(int[] coords) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    coords[0] = getX(scanner, coords);
    coords[1] = getY(scanner, coords);
    scanner.close()
    return coords;
}
```

And an example get method:

```
private void getX(Scanner scanner, int[] coords) {
    System.out.println("Please enter x coordinate:");
    coords[0] = scanner.nextInt(); //Change 0 index to 1 for getY
}
```

Comment: The 2D array has already been made, the function just needs to place a value in the coordinate put in by the user through a scanner into the array.

Comment: Then instead of creating a new array, pass in the old one! I'll edit now to show what I mean.

Comment: I understand. I do need to make two functions in order to get the right coords for a 2D array then. This would work only for a 1d array right? I'll accept your answer any ways because it has made me understand what to do.

Comment: I'll edit to show a solution that avoids having to repeat the input code. Good Question.

Comment: Note the quotation in my question, as this is all I can follow by at the moment

Comment: I've showed the consolidated solution. If you're forced to follow teacher's silly conventions then do so by creating 2 separate `getx` and `gety` methods. It's not worth fighting. I'll edit one final time to show a solution that avoids repeated scanner opening/closing even with 2 methods.

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you. I'm not given much information on how to do this code, but I think two methods are the best way to do this.

Comment: Your question has changed significantly since the first post. Careful as I have used a 1 dimensional array, and your OP now describes a 2 dimensional array. You'll have to update my methods slightly to deal with this.

Comment: I thought my first post stated it was for a 2D Array. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You can return a 2-element array, concatenate the values into a string separated by a delimiter, or create a `Dimension` class that contains x- and y- coordinates.

```
String promptCoords()
{
    return promptX() + ":" + promptY();
}

int[] promptCoords()
{
    return new int[]{promptX(), promptY()};
}

Dimension promptCoords()
{
    return new Dimension(promptX(), promptY());
}

private class Dimension 
{
    int x, y;

    Dimension(int x, int y) 
    { 
        this.x  = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

int promptX(){return -1;}
int promptY(){return -1;}
```

Comment: Sorry I should of clarified, I can only use so much within java for the game(its apart of my computing course test). So I don't believe I can use a Dimension, I need to scanner the x and y coordinate from the user, and return those values to be entered in the 2D array already made.