# how to invoke constructor in main method?

Tags: java

I'm writing a code in which in its main method I create an object. But I don't know how to call its constructor. 
here is my code:

```
//This class calculate the greatest common divisor of two number 
import static java.lang.Math.min;
public class Calculate2
{
    private int num1,num2;
    public Calculate2(int num1 , int num2)
    {
        this.num1=num1;
        this.num2=num2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       Calculate2 gcd = new Calculate2();
       gcd.GCD();
    }
    public void GCD()
    {
        int min_num;
        int greatestcommondivisor=0;
        min_num = min(num1,num2);
        for(int commondivisor=1;commondivisor <= min_num;commondivisor++)
        {
           if(num1%commondivisor==0 &&  num2%commondivisor==0)
           {
               greatestcommondivisor=commondivisor;
           }
           commondivisor++;
        }
        System.out.println(greatestcommondivisor);
    }//End of the method gcd


}//End of the class calculate2
```

how should I call the constructor?

Comment: You have to pass 2 `int`s to the constructor, since that's how you've defined it. It's similar to calling a regular method.

Comment: when I pass 2 int to it,there is another error!

Comment: No it doesn't, I just tried your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fact that you created your own constructor means that default one will not be added by compiler.
2. Also your constructor looks like

   ```
   public Calculate2(int num1, int num2) {
   }
   ```

   which means it requires two `int` arguments, so you need to pass some `int` values to it like

   ```
   new Calculate2(42,24);
   ```

Comment: I want to get the num1 & num2 from user not some defults!

Comment: Then ask user to give you some values so you could you use them as constructors arguments. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19532416/1393766 to see example how you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors in a class are called right when we declare the object. Thus declare your object like this

```
Calculate2 obj = new Calculate2(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor shares the same name as the class, so when u create a new object (`gcd`) like below

```
Calculate2 gcd = new Calculate2();
```

You have already called the default constructor of the class `Calculate2`

But since, you have declared a constructor with parameters:

```
public Calculate2(int num1 , int num2)
```

This means that the constructor of the class requires 2 parameters in it `num1` and `num2`, so you have to call it like

```
Calculate2 obj_gcd = new Calculate2(100,200);
```

Comment: But `Calculate2` doesn't have a default constructor since the OP has explicitly defined another constructor.

Comment: @arshajii :  patience is virtue mate.....wait for people to update their answer....if u dont feel its correct after first 5 mins, then drop a comment ( *learnt this through personal experience* )!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Constructor is parameteris constructor

```
  You must pass value to parameteris  Construcor
  You Can Call With differnt of type

  int i=10;
  int j=5;
  Calculate2 gcd = new Calculate2(i,j);
```

or

```
  new  Calculate2(10,20);
```

or

```
   Calculate2 gcd = new Calculate2(10,20);
```

or

```
    Calculate2 gcd;
    gcd = new Calculate2(15,20);
```