# Read from Object in java

Tags: java, object

```
Haj_Omra pr =new Promises( "Reem", 19,"10089", "italian","9/8/8" ,  " " );
```

//here i have to add information

**but i want user to input from object , how can i do it ?**
how can i use the Scanner ?

i tried to put scanner inside the class but it's doesn't work ?

```
Class Check{
public void Sc(String ID){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a ID: ");
}
```

please any idea ??

Comment: *i want user to input from object* what do you mean? The user can only input stuff from the keyboard AFAIK, otherwise you might need to read some input from a file or a stream.

Comment: You might want to check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5287561/1540818 It is not the accepted answer, but it's very useful to learn how to deal very simply with user input.

Comment: you should put the statement `System.out.print("Please enter a ID: ");` before taking input from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should not access object's attributes directly it should be done through `setter` and `getter` methods. So you should define the `class` you want with the attributes needed and their `setter` and `getter` methods. for example some thing like:

```
    public class MyClass
{
    private string myField; //"private" means access to this is restricted

    public string getMyField()
    {
         //include validation, logic, logging or whatever you like here
        return this.myField;
    }
    public void setMyField(string value)
    {
             //include more logic
             this.myField = value;
    }
}
```

**Quoted from: [tutorial on getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/tutorial-on-getters-and-setters)**

After that you need to create new object of that `class` and set its attribute's value through the `setter` methods where the value is an user input.

```
MyClass myClassObj=new MyClass();   // creating new instance of MyClass 
System.out.println("Please enter an ID: ");
Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput=scan.nextLine();   // get user input

myClassObj.setMyField(userInput);   // setting myFiled attribute
```

and just for testing purpose you can get `myFiled` value through `getter` method as follow:

```
System.out.println("The data enterd by user is: "+myClassObj.getMyFiled());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum.. just add

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

to get the user entry after you declared your scanner, like :

```
public void Sc(String ID){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
}
```