# Basic Java Addition Calculator

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorldJavaMain 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first number.");
        int inputA = userInputScanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the second number.");
        int inputB = userInputScanner.nextLine();

        int sumOfInputs = inputA + inputB;

        System.out.println(inputA + " + " + inputB  + " = " + sumOfInputs);

    }

}
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: int inputA = userInputScanner.nextLine();

Comment: This won't even compile.  If you try, you'll get an error message that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: thats what i wrote...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get basic user input for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java)

Comment: Actually, you don't have any details other than "can someone where I went wrong". If you want actual help you need to provide details. Is it compiling? If not what errors and line numbers? Do you get wrong output? If so what do you expect vs what you are getting? These types of things.

Comment: @user3832004 No, you didn't. In fact you haven't described the actual problem you're experiencing at all. As a general rule when posting on SO, you need to be specific about the problem or question you have. Explain where the error is occurring, what error messages you're receiving, unexpected versus expected behaviour, etc. Otherwise, you're asking somebody to pick through your code and perform the debugging that you yourself should have done originally.

Answer (score 1):

```
int inputA = userInputScanner.nextLine();
```

should change to

```
int inputA = userInputScanner.nextInt();
```

because nextline doesn't return int .or you could use

`Integer.parseInt(userInputScanner.nextLine())`

same thing to inputB

Answer (score 0):

Use `userInputScanner.nextInt();`

userInputScanner.nextLine() reads a String line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int inputA = userInputScanner.nextInt();
int inputB = userInputScanner.nextInt();
int sumOfInputs = inputA + inputB;
System.out.println(inputA + " + " + inputB  + " = " + sumOfInputs);
```

check this http://ideone.com/0eR41r