# how can i modify main method to get input and output from the comandline?

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

Instead of hard coding to read the `infile` and `outfile`, I want to read from the command line. How would I do that?

```
/**
 * reads a file and creates a histogram from it
 * @param args string of argument
 * @precondition none
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Histogram hist = new  Histogram();
    FileInputController input = new FileInputController(hist);
    FileOutputController output = new FileOutputController(hist);

    try {
        input.readWords("infile.txt");
        output.writeWords("outfile.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("exception caught! somthing went wrong: " + exception.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("exception caught! somthing went wrong: " + exception.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.exit(1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: use `args`. something like `java helloworld.java file1.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the user input in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WordHistogram hist = new  WordHistogram();
    FileInputController input = new FileInputController(hist);
    FileOutputController output = new FileOutputController(hist);

    try {
        input.readWords(args[0]);  //args[0] is the first argument passed while launching Java
        output.writeWords(args[1]);  //args[1] is the second argument passed while launching Java
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.out.println("exception caught! somthing went wrong: " + exception.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("exception caught! somthing went wrong: " + exception.getMessage());
    } finally {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Run your program like: `java YourClassName infile.txt outfile.txt`

In `main(String[] args)`, `args` is an array of Strings which contains values of arguments passed while launching Java.

Please DO read [Oracle docs about command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

to get integer value use like this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
```

to get string use this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String username = scanner.nextLine();
```

and for output use just `System.out.println("your text here");`