# Java - Read keyboard input and write it into a text file

Tags: java, text, input

Is there a way to read input from the command line and write it into a text file?

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //Yes, I am clueless so I have no idea what to put
        }
}
```

Comment: Read user input in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java) and then save the file (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm). That's really it.

Comment: The JDK demos and samples pack, available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ , has an example of this very thing under its demo/jfc/Notepad directory.

Comment: For basic stuff like this, always look at the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) first.

Answer (score 3):

Since I assume you are a beginner in Java, i wrote a short code sample with self-explanatory comments. The application runs on the command line and reads line by line, where a line ends by hitting the enter key. If you type "EXIT", the application quits. The text file to be written is located at `C:\Folder\Text.txt`.

This is a very basic example, so just extend it to your needs. For better platform independence, you can substitute the hardcoded `\\` slash by `File.separator`. As a note to the finally block: In newer versions of Java (>= 7), you can save a lot of boilerplate code by using the `try-with` syntax. Read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), if you are interested.

You can inform yourself about the basic I/O mechanisms in the tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm).

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // The reader and writer objects must be declared BEFORE
        // the try block, otherwise they are not 'visible' to close
        // in the finally block
        Scanner reader = null;
        FileWriter writer = null;
        String inputText;

        try {

            // Reader and writer are instantiated within the try block,
            // because they can already throw an IOException
            reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Do not forget, '\\' is the escape sequence for a backslash
            writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Folder\\Text.txt");

            // We read line by line, a line ends with a newline character
            // (in Java a '\n') and then we write it into the file
            while (true) {

                inputText = reader.nextLine();

                // If you type 'EXIT', the application quits
                if (inputText.equals("EXIT")) {
                    break;
                }

                writer.write(inputText);

                // Add the newline character, because it is cut off by
                // the reader, when reading a whole line
                writer.write("\n");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // This exception may occur while reading or writing a line
            System.out.println("A fatal exception occurred!");

        } finally {

            // The finally branch is ALWAYS executed after the try
            // or potential catch block execution

            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }

            try {

                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // This second catch block is a clumsy notation we need in Java,
                // because the 'close()' call can itself throw an IOException.
                System.out.println("Closing was not successful.");

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, this can be very concise as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Stream<String> stream = in.lines().limit(20); // 20 is number of lines you want to read

    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("FileName.txt", "UTF-8")) {
        stream.map(s -> s)
              .forEachOrdered(pw::println);
    }
     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```