# I have to add a string to a string for an assignment

Tags: java, arrays, string, wildcard

I'm having trouble fully understanding arrays. I understand what a int array is, a set of numbers grouped together with their own locations, but I don't understand the purpose of string arrays vs strings, or how to get the user to input a string.

So, I have to make it so that the user enters a string with a % somewhere, and then another string, where the % is, the second string they enter needs to go there. I am NOT looking for a copy paste thing, but an explanation on what code I should use an what it does for that action.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Umm. [Java User input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)? Unclear what the issue is, or why you even need arrays here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`java.util.Scanner`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)

You would enter a String containing a `%` character

Then, you [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) that value with a second input string.

No arrays necessary...