# setting java array length via user input

Tags: java, arrays

How would I initialize an Array within an object who's length is that of a user's input?  I want to set the number of bats via user input, and make that the array length, then within the array of `basesAchieved`, I want to set a number based on user input (1-4) representing the base achieved.

```
// set up a Batter
public class Batter
{
    private String batterName;
    private int numberOfBats;
    private int[] basesAchieved;

    // fill fields with empty data, how is this done with an array??
    public Batter()
    {
        this("", 0,0);
    }

    //
    public Batter(String batterName, int numberOfBats, int[] basesAchieved)
    {
        this.batterName = batterName;
        this.numberOfBats = numberOfBats;
        this.basesAchieved = basesAchieved;
    }

    public void setBatterName(String batterName)
    {
        this.batterName = batterName;
    }

    public String getBatterName()
    {
        return batterName;
    }

    public void setNumberOfBats(int numberOfBats)
    {
        this.numberOfBats = numberOfBats;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBats()
    {
        return numberOfBats;
    }

    // want to set an array to get a number (1-4) for each number of @ bats     
    // (numberOfBats). 
    public void setBasesAchieved(int[] basesAchieved)
    {
        this.basesAchieved = ;
    }

    public int getBasesAchieved()
    {
        return basesAchieved;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `setter` method you should assign `this.basesAchieved = basesAchieved;`. If you want to initialize the basesAchieved with a length then just: `int[] basesAchieved = new int[yourlength]` in the class you initialize `Batter` class, then call the `setter` method of this class

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your class where you try to use an int array.

```
public Batter()
{
    this("", 0, new int[0]);
}

// skipped...

public void setBasesAchieved(int[] basesAchieved)
{
    this.basesAchieved = basesAchieved;
}

public int[] getBasesAchieved()
{
    return basesAchieved;
}
```

This question explains how to get user input [How can I get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)

> One of the simplest ways is to use a Scanner object as follows:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
```

You can use this method to read the number of `numberOfBats` and create your object with the right array length. Then you can keep asking the user for input and put those into the `basesAchieved` array. Or you can ask the reader for all inputs first and then create your object.