# Having trouble with my bicycle java program setup

Tags: java

My assignment is to create a program that will give the MPH of a bicycle given the `gear (1 - 3)` and `cadence (1-100)`.

- 1st gear MPH = cadence/12,
- 2nd gear MPH = cadence/6,
- 3rd gear MPH = cadence/4.

We have set a class and need to run a test program.  Here is what I have so far, I am just confused as to where I run the looping structure with user input and where my return statements should be:

```
public class Bicycle
{
    private int bike;
    private int gear = 1;
    private int cadence = 1;
    private int speed = 1;

    public void changeGear(int getGear)
    {

        gear = getGear;
    }

    public void changeCadence(int getCadence)
    {
        cadence = getCadence;
    }

    public void MPH(int getMPH)
    {
        speed = getMPH;
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BicycleTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Bicycle bike;
        bike = new Bicycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your logic should go in the main method, either directly or in a method that you call in main(). Bicycle is a representation of the Bike object, you shouldn't put application logic in that type of class.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew.  Do you think I am on the right path so far?

Comment: Sorry, soconnell80, went home for the day, but yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to `set` and `get` the attributs of an instance, use the naming conventions (`getStuff` and `setStuff`). Then `speed` is not a property of your bike, it changes and depends of other attributs, also when setting new values, check out if it's in you requried range.

To get the speed, just check `gear` and return the good result :

```
public class Bicycle {

    private int bike;
    private int gear;
    private int cadence;

    public int getGear() {
        return gear;
    }    
    public void setGear(int gear) {
        if (gear >= 1 && gear <= 3) {
            this.gear = gear;
        }
    }

    public int getCadence() {
        return cadence;
    }
    public void setCadence(int cadence) {
        if (cadence >= 1 && cadence <= 100) {
            this.cadence = cadence;
        }
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        if (gear == 1) {
            return cadence / 12.0;
        } else if (gear == 2) {
            return cadence / 6.0;
        } else if(gear == 3{
            return cadence / 4.0;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this : instanciate a `Bike`, ask the user for the `gear` and `cadence` and you're done :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bicycle bike = new Bicycle();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Give the gear :");
    bike.setGear(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));

    System.out.println("Give the cadence :");
    bike.setCadence(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));

    double speed = bike.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this further.  I do have a follow up question...what is "Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine)?  I haven't seen that yet.

Comment: @soconnell80 I personnaly always use `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())` rather than `sc.nextInt()` to be sure to avoid problem with return line char, it just read the lines typed and convert it to `int`

Comment: Okay, is this connected then to the user input?  Again, I apologize for not understanding.  Meaning, another way of using import java.util.Scanner?

Comment: @soconnell80 you should read about asking a user input, System.in is the keyboard, and Scanner is used to listen to that input : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java

Comment: thank you!  I appreciate all of your help!  This makes sense to me!

Comment: @soconnell80 np ;) I let you upvote/accept the answer so ;)