# How to put something like a semicolon or colon after asking user for prompt in Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am trying to learn Java and was specifically learning about User Input using Scanner class.

I was wondering if you can add something like a ':' or ';' after a prompt.

My understanding is somewhat like this

```
Scanner var1 = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates a new object of scanner class
String var2 = var1.next(); //Stores input in a string variable
```

So what should be the way to put a ":" after the prompt, in the same line?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)

Comment: @jschnasse - No, this question is about how to *output* a prompt.

Comment: Please update your question to give us the code from the Scanner class so we can show you exactly where the output is happening and what you can do to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a prompt on the same line as the user input by using System.out.print(prompt)

Note that this is not the same as System.out.println(prompt), which puts a newline after the string to be printed.

Example:

```
System.out.print("Enter your value: ");
String value = myScanner.next();
```