# How to use CMD Variables via Java?

Tags: java, cmd

I want to use variables in CMD via Java runtime. What I have tried is this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"ping localhost &&" +
                                                   "set /p userInput=Do you want to exit? [y/n] &&" +
                                                   "echo %userInput%\"");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
```

But instead of giving the value of variable `userInput` it displays the variable name as it is with `%` symbol on both sides:

```
Pinging Desktop-PC [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time=1ms
Reply from ::1: time=1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
Do you want to exit? [y/n] y
%userInput%
```

whereas if I run the same command from CMD it gives me the value of variable

```
D:\>set /p userInput=Do you want to exit? [y/n]
Do you want to exit? [y/n] y

D:\>echo %userInput%
y
```

Comment: Consider using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of Runtime, it gives you more flexibility and more readability executing your command

Comment: Also why don't you use a [Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java) to capture user input? You can just run your process, output the result to `System.out` and ask the user if he wants to run the process again.

Comment: Try `runtime.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /V /K \"ping localhost &&" +` and `"echo !userInput!\"");`. Is this working now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need [delayed](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) [expansion](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php) which is enabled in cmd with the `/V` option. Therefore, you should use:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /V /k \"ping localhost &&" +
                                                   "set /p userInput=Do you want to exit? [y/n] &&" +
                                                   "echo !userInput!\"");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
```

which should work for you.