# How to get the revenue per monthly?

Tags: java

I want to make a program for a boat. It will ask the `passenger` number of passengers how much they each get paid. Then, it will give me the revenue and based on that, I will calculate the monthly revenue.

```
package com.company;

class Boat {
    private int passenger;  // total number of passengers
    private int cost; // cost per passenger
    private int RevenueCalculator;


    public Boat(int newpassenger, int newcost) {
        this.passenger = newpassenger;
        this.cost = newcost;
    }

    public int computeRevenue() {
        int RevenueCalculator;
        RevenueCalculator = this.cost * this.passenger;
        System.out.println("How many passengers");
        System.out.println("Cost per passenger");
        return RevenueCalculator;

    }
}
```

I ran this program and this error pop up:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.Main.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Well printing after the return is not correct. Otherwise, looks reasonable assuming all passengers paid the same price.

Comment: can you tell me how I can make input such as number of pasenger and how much they paid to get the revenue. i used print beacuse i wanted to see it in the termina,l

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is meant to address specific technical issues, like "I tried this code and got X but I expected Y. How do I fix it?" If we're being generous here, your question is more along the lines of design assistance. "Am I heading in the right direction" isn't a technical question. Please familiarize yourself with the rubric for [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions which will receive good answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes and what are the differences between NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn)

Answer (score 0):

See here how to get user input in java:

[How can I get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)

Also you will need to create another 'test' class and set there a main function where you use the `Boat` class object.