# how can i run a set of code based on user input

Tags: java

I want to have a program that asks the user for an input of either yes or no. if no, it does nothing, but if it is a yes, it will run the following code.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class GettingCurrentDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //getting current date and time using Date class
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
        Date dateobj = new Date();
        System.out.println(df.format(dateobj));

        /*
         * getting current date time using calendar class
         * 
         * An Alternative of above
         */
        Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();

        System.out.println(df.format(calobj.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just look on google : java ask for user input maybe ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Please review documentation for how to receive use input.  I think this gives a succinct and basic explanation: [Accepting Input from a User](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/user_input.html)

Another user also provided a good link to review.

You need to combine this with an "if" statement: [Java If ... Else](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp)

A simple example based off the code your provided:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GettingCurrentDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Print current date? (yes/no)");

        String input = in.nextLine();


        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
            Date dateobj = new Date();
            System.out.println(df.format(dateobj));
        }
    }
}
```