# How to create a java object that gets values from users?

Tags: javascript, java, object, project

So i am working on a java project in which i have very little experience.I have to create 2 objects,x and y.Object x which contains given values using a constructor.Object y ,which i am stuck, requires values given by the user from the keyboard and i cant find a way to do that.Later on i have to compare these to objects for another question that is being asked.Can anyone help me out with object y?
I am being taught java for not over a month and i am struggling to finish this project before the deadline.Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-the-user-input-in-java
You need to learn to search this kind of questions online before opening new threads.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find here how to read values from a user :
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp 
 The w3schools.com site has a full Java tutorial(and not only) that's gonna help you a lot! Good luck finishing that project!