# How to take input from file and search that input in java?

Tags: java, input, file-io

I am new to stackoverflow and programming and I am high school student can you please help.
[Here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEpV0.jpg)

The data file used in this question has folllowing data

```
ID:Name:Final 
18273640:Annette Adams:98
93840219:Mary Beard:87 
23958552:Antoinette Brown:79 
23958231:Claribel Cone:78 
23958548:Ema Chang:69 
23958664:Heesook Kim:98 
23958115:Larry Liu:98 
23958238:Brad Lee:53 
18273165:Eric Ko:95 
18273239:Richard Ko:96 
18273475:Shawn Tornton:98 
18273427:Omar Maghardi:78 
18273975:Scott Yau:59 
18273231:Glenn Ikonomov:86 
92839115:Scott Trouchon:69 
92839985:Patric Zhou:88 
92839344:Zhanfang Li:82 
92839342:Robert Bloomingdale:91 
92839633:Patricia Garibaldi:59 
92839654:Svetlana Rusova:48 
92839443:Aleksei Titov:99 
92839864:Xiaowei Young:96 
92839428:Guan Wang:46
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Split your problem into smaller steps. Each of those steps is already most likely asked on this site. For instance if you ask on google `java read file line by line site:stackoverflow.com` you will get many related questions like [How can I read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5868369).

Comment: Also don't include task information as image/link - [more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Can you write answer for me I dont have experience in programming It will be great help from you!

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a forum to answer homework questions, I can give you some pointers that will help you get started:

**Things your program needs to do**

To allow the user to search the file, you program must be able to:

1. Read the user's input
2. Read the text file
3. (Optional) Load the data in the text file into an easy-to-search data structure
4. Search the text file's contents (or your data structure) for the student's information

**Read the user's input**

This will answer that: [How to get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-the-user-input-in-java)

**Read the text file**

This will answer that: [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

**(Optional) Load data into data structure**

This is optional but it will make the next step easier. You essentially need to parse the string data from the file into a data structure.

One way to do this is to create a class called `Student` with fields `String name;` , `String id;` and `Integer score;`. Then store all the students in a list like `List<Student>` or `HashMap<String, Student>` where the key is an id

Note, you can call `"92839428:Guan Wang:46".split(":")` for example to separate the different components on each line

**Search for the student**

If you create a data structure like above, you just need to find the `Student` object which matches the user's input

Comment: Thanks alot Aziz ,Its not my homework question I am in learning phase of java and found this question and I got no clue so I just asked.

Comment: I am high school student I dont know much about data structures I know about searching but how to do that in file so I am stuck.If you can write the solution it would be really great help