# Doing a yes or no where yes continues but terminates after asking

Tags: java

After putting all the numbers input the loop terminates and the program ends, after asking whether to continue or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class coding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String choose;
        int i;
        double ans;

        do {
            int num1= in.nextInt();
            int num2= in.nextInt();
            int num3= in.nextInt();
            int num4 = in.nextInt();
            int num5 = in.nextInt();
             ans = (num1+num2+num3+num4+num5)/5;
            System.out.println(ans);
            //in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Continue the program Yes or N?");
            
            choose = in.nextLine();


        }while (choose.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-the-user-input-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the program will continue on `Yes` and will end on `N`, so you need to change it the while condition to this: `!choose.equalsIgnoreCase("N")` to check while its not true then iterate.

secondly you used `choose = in.nextLine();` which cause error on next iteration, which you need to change it to `choose = in.next();` to run without error.

`choose = in.nextLine();` it cause to store the <kbd>enter</kbd> value in next call of `in.nextInt()` and throw an error.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String choose;
int i;
double ans;

do {
    int num1 = in.nextInt();
    int num2 = in.nextInt();
    int num3 = in.nextInt();
    int num4 = in.nextInt();
    int num5 = in.nextInt();
    ans = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5) / 5;
    System.out.println(ans);
    // in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Continue the program Yes or N?");
    choose = in.next();

} while (!choose.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
```