# Program terminating unexpectedly: Java

Tags: java, input

I am making a program where the program says "Hey!" and if the user says "hi" reply with: "What's up?" back. the problem is that the program terminated before I could even type my input. I am really confused. I tried other stack posts but that did not work. Please help!
Relevant code:

```java
import java.util.*;  
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hey!");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (sc.equals("hi")) {
              System.out.println("Whats up?");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

If there is any way to shorten the code or make it more efficient please include that too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-the-user-input-in-java)

Comment: You compare sc (the Scanner reference) with a String. That will never be true. Use sc.next() in your if statement, meaning your condition should be if (sc.next().equals("hi"))

Comment: @user15793316 Ok. Just started working on that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanner class isn't the user input, you can use it to get user input for example,

```
String input = scanner.next();
```

Your code should be

```java
import java.util.*;  
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hey!");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.next(); 
        if (input.equals("hi")) {
            System.out.println("Whats up?");
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! I am very grateful.

Comment: You're most welcome :D