# How to make the program ask the user for input until they give a valid response?

Tags: java, user-input

could you please help me to make this program to get a correct number? The program should check the input type, it should be int. Also, the program should check that the value is from 1 to 10. If these conditions are true, the value should be assigned to correctNumber. So far I came up to this piece of code but I have difficulties in making it work properly.

```
System.out.println("Enter a number from 1 to 10:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!scanner.hasNextInt() || !isCorrectNumber(scanner.nextInt())) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
                scanner.next();
            }
            int correctNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    
        }
    private static boolean isCorrectNumber(int n) {
        return size >= 1 && size <= 10;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-the-user-input-in-java)

Comment: You are asking twice for user input. (scanner.nextInt)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for input 2 times in your while condition
Use a variable to save the input and then work with that

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    String x = input.readLine();
    while (!isInt(x)) {
        x = input.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I ask for input, i get a String, now i have to check if this string can be a number. For that i've created a boolean function isInt(String)
Takes the String and returns if it can be a number.

```
public static boolean isInt(String str) {//function that checks if String can be parsed into an integer
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(str);
        return true;
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope i've been helpfull